# Date format issue in SSIS package day is converted to year and year is converted to day

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to insert a date value in a `datetime` datatype column of the SQL Server through `SSIS` package.

In the source *.`csv` file it is in the format `dd-mm-yy`.

When I am manually running the SSIS package there is no error. the date format from the .csv file `DD-MM-YY` is successfully inserted in the SQL server database in `DD-MM-YYYY` format.

But when I am running the same package through Jobs in SQL Server Agent it gets converted to an incorrect date format because DAY is converted to YEAR and YEAR is converted to DAY.

For example if the date in the .csv file is `15-03-13` (DD-MM-YY) it gets inserted as `13-03-2015`.

Tried a lot to get the date in the correct format in the database but all in vain.

Please suggest how to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To restate the issue: flat file source, data in dd-mm-yy format. You import, date is parsed as dd-mm-yy (desired). When executed through SQL Agent, date is parsed as yy-mm-dd. If that's accurate, it smells like a localisation issue. If you RDC into the server and manually execute the package, what format is used? `dtexec.exe /file myPackage.dtsx`

Comment: @billinkc I would said the same. Check your system towards SQL database localization settings.

Answer (score 0):

Example how to do it, Example data:

[image]

1. You need to convert column to string:

[image]

2.Then Convert to Ms Sql Date format:

[image]

3.Derived Column Code:

`SUBSTRING([Copy of Datee],7,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Copy of Datee],4,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Copy of Datee],1,2)`

`(DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING([Copy of Datee],7,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Copy of Datee],4,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Copy of Datee],1,2))`

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the derived column you have to write:

```
DateReceived == "" ? NULL(DT_DATE) : (DT_DATE)((LEN(RTRIM(DateReceived)) == 10 ? SUBSTRING(DateReceived,7,4) : ("20" + SUBSTRING(DateReceived,7,2))) + "-" + SUBSTRING(DateReceived,4,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(DateReceived,1,2))
```